# add/remove form missing "restrict" and "maxlength"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble with my add/remove fields code.

If I run this code in [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) and I make extra fields with the adding button.

```
<script>
        var i = 1;
  function addKid(){
    if (i <= 4){
       i++;
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.width = "44%";
      div.style.height = "26px";
      div.style.color = "white";
      div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');
     div.innerHTML = 'Child : <input id="child_'+i+'" type="text" name="child_'+i+'" > Ages : <input id="ages_'+i+'" type="text" name="ages_'+i+'"><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onClick="addKid()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)">';
      document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
      }
      }
      function removeKid(div) {
        document.getElementById('kids').removeChild( div.parentNode );
        i--; }

</script>

 <div id="kids">
 Child : <input id="child_1" type="text" name="child_1" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('child_1')" maxlength="50">
 Ages :  <input id="ages_1" type="text" name="ages_1" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('ages_1')" maxlength="10"><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onClick="addKid()" value="+" />
   </div>
```

Then if I use firebug on the first fields I get this.

```
<input id="child_1" type="text" maxlength="50" onkeyup="restrict('child_1')" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" name="child_1">

<input id="ages_1" type="text" maxlength="10" onkeyup="restrict('ages_1')" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" name="ages_1">
```

On my extra added fields I get this with firebug.

```
<input id="child_2" type="text" name="child_2">

<input id="ages_2" type="text" name="ages_2">
```

How can I add a "restrict" and "maxlength" to the extra added fields like this.

```
<input id="child_2" type="text" name="child_2" onkeyup="restrict('child_1')" maxlength="50">

<input id="ages_2" type="text" name="ages_2" onkeyup="restrict('ages_1')" maxlength="10">
```

If I can make up 5 extra fields with the button, how can they each get a "restrict" and "maxlength" like this.

```
<input id="child_3" type="text" name="child_3" onkeyup="restrict('child_1')" maxlength="50">

<input id="ages_3" type="text" name="ages_3" onkeyup="restrict('ages_1')" maxlength="10">


<input id="child_4" type="text" name="child_4" onkeyup="restrict('child_1')" maxlength="50">

<input id="ages_4" type="text" name="ages_4" onkeyup="restrict('ages_1')" maxlength="10">


<input id="child_5" type="text" name="child_5" onkeyup="restrict('child_1')" maxlength="50">

<input id="ages_5" type="text" name="ages_5" onkeyup="restrict('ages_1')" maxlength="10">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these attributes inside `input` tags when you create them:

```
div.innerHTML = 'Child : <input id="child_'+i+'" type="text" name="child_'+i+'" maxlength="50" onkeyup="restrict(\'child_'+i+'\')"> Ages : <input id="ages_'+i+'" type="text" name="ages_'+i+'" maxlength="10" onkeyup="restrict(\'ages_'+i+'\')"><input type="button" onClick="addKid()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)">';
```

When you set HTML code with JavaScript you might need sometimes to escape quotes, like in this case:

```
onkeyup="restrict(\'child_'+i+'\')"
```

Also you should not:

- Repeat an `id` attribute
- Use `()` inside `id` attribute

Comment: Thank you for the help, you are awesome. :-)  .. and thanks again.

Comment: @DerRed Happy to help:). If my answer solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted.